# Oracle Sql select all values in a row without using aggregate functions and procedures

Tags: sql, oracle, join, string-aggregation

**I have this code:**

```
select eto.id,( epe.surname || ' ' || epe.name  || ' ' || epe.patronymic) fio
                        from employee_trip_orders eto
                        left join employee_card_order_links ecol
                        on eto.id = ecol.trip_order_id
                        left join employee_trip_cards etc
                        on ecol.trip_card_id = etc.employee_trip_card_id 
                        left join eip_persons.employees epe
                        on etc.employee_id = epe.employee_id
                        where eto.id=2223
                        order by eto.id
```

**and result of executing this code**

```
id     fio
------------
2223 John Smith Brown
2223 Jack Orange Apple
2223 Jordan Stinky Tomato
```

I would like to transform this into single row with comma separators

```
id     fio
-------------------------------
2223 |  John Smith Brown,
     |  Jack Orange Apple,
     |  Jordan Stinky Tomato
-------------------------------
```

How can i achieve this without using external functions, group by and agregate functions? Thanks

Comment: No-no, @a_horse. "... without using external functions, group by and agregate functions". If I were you (the OP), I'd write it down on a piece of paper, putting comma wherever appropriate. That approach doesn't use external functions, etc.

Comment: @Littlefoot: aggregating without aggregate functions seems a rather futile attempt

Comment: What's wrong with using `listagg()`?

Comment: @Littlefoot mb i need one more select?

Comment: @a_horse ("... seems a rather futile attempt"). Of course it does. Goes into "how to make simple things complex".

Comment: Why do you need to do this without external functions, group by and aggregate functions? Aggregation is exactly what you need here. It's a bit like saying "how can I play the piano without touching the keys?" ... you're making things unnaturally hard for yourself by constraining yourself like this. What's your reason?

Comment: Sorry everyone, i formulate my question wrong, i just need a concatenate strings in one field without group by. I just try to use listagg like this select auid, listagg(title, ', ') from study_group but, how can i do without group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `connect by` query, but it is slower and more complicated than simple `listagg()`.

```
select id, ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(fio, ', '), ', ') names
  from (select row_number() over (partition by id order by fio) rn, id, fio from t)
  where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  connect by id = prior id and rn = prior rn + 1
  start with rn = 1
```

<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=325643f4f9e5e4c1ad67fac7b3287e13)</sup>